# How can I extract the HTML Report summary to display in the body of the email sent from Azure Pipelines

Tags: c#, azure, selenium-webdriver

We are currently using Jenkins to build our automation tests, and are moving to Azure DevOps. Jenkins will send an email upon completion with the html of the report summary as the body so testers can easily see the results of the test run. We would like the email sent from our Azure Pipeline to do the same. Has anyone had any luck in extracting that html to the body of the email sent from Azure? We use Specflow, C#, and command line to run our tests.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyXqo.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTbsc.png)

I have tried adding the path of the report to the email body using the ISHTML option